# How come all ViewController.h files are unchecked by default in Target Membership

Tags: xcode, appstore-approval

All VC.h files are unchecked by default in Xcode 6.1's  Target Membership under the file inspector yet all VC.m files are checked. Am I supposed to send my Xcode project to App store with VC.h target memberships unchecked or am I supposed to check those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct behavior, only .m or .mm files should have target memberships.

You can find the Target attached source files in, ***Project Settings > Target > Build Phases > Compile Sources***

If your viewcontroller name is there, it means it is attached to Target output.

Hope this helps.

[image]